# How do humans remember information?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, memory

When conversing, I often find myself using words or conveying ideas that I wasn't aware that I knew, nor whether these words/ideas were actually relevant to the conversation. It is only after googling these words that I realise that indeed they are relevant.

I also find myself remembering some particular information which I was adamant that was no longer in my memory. This is often triggered some some string of events, seemingly deterministic in nature, in such a way that if those particular set of events weren't sequenced into the order they were, I would never remember that.

This leads me onto how we humans actually memorise? Is the deterministic nature of the brain's neural network relevant to the randomness of memorization?

Comment: A bit like [déjà vu](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13656/7604) of information.

Comment: Some memory is auto-associative, so triggering a tiny part of a memory might bring back the whole memory. You can find more details [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/27935/26809). Just a small part of the answer, I'm sure there's more ways to look at it.